# UITests in Xcode 7 finds wrong 'Next' button

Tags: xcode, xctest, ui-testing, xcode-ui-testing

I have a test that looks like the following:

```
func testNextButtonDisabled() {
  let app = XCUIApplication()
  XCTAssertFalse(app.buttons["Next"].enabled)
}
```

This test fails because, in addition to my own "Next" button that I've created, the keyboard return button is labeled 'Next'. This test fails with the error:

> UI Testing Failure - Multiple matches found

How can I differentiate between my own 'Next' button and the keyboard 'Next' button?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The specific solution to this problem is to look for elements that are descendants of the main window.

```
func testNextButtonDisabled() {
  let app = XCUIApplication()
  XCTAssertFalse(app.childrenMatchingType(.Window).elementBoundByIndex(0).buttons["Next"].enabled)
}
```

For a general solution to solve problems like this: In Xcode run the "Record UI Test" again to see how Xcode thinks you should be referencing the element in which you're interested.